# C++ variable that holds any specialization of class template

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming, template-specialization

I need to be able to store any specialization of a template in a variable eg:

```
template<T>
class Grid {
  int GetRows();
  int GetTypeOfColumn(int col);
  //...etc...
}

//EDIT:
Grid<int>::GetTypeofColumn(int col) {
   return col == 0 ? STRING_COL_TYPE : INT_COL_TYPE;
}
Grid<string>::GetTypeofColumn(int col) {
   return STRING_COL_TYPE;
}
//End EDIT

class Foo {
  Grid<int>* aBunchOfNumbers;
  Grid<string>* aBunchOfStrings;
  //...etc...
}

//in some function, say `wants` is an enum, and foo is gotten from somewhere:
Foo* foo; 
switch wants {
  case NUMBERS:
    std::cout << "Rows: " << foo->aBunchOfNumbers->GetRows() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Col0 is: " << foo->aBunchOfNumbers->GetTypeofColumn(0) << std::endl;
    //...etc...
    break;
  case STRINGS:
    std::cout << "Rows: " << foo->aBunchOfNumbers->GetRows() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Col0 is: " << foo->aBunchOfNumbers->GetTypeofColumn(0) << std::endl;
    //...etc...
    break;
}
```

it would be easier to do:

```
Foo* foo;
Grid* grid;
switch wants {
  case NUMBERS:
    grid = foo->aBunchOfNumbers;
    break;
  case STRINGS:
    grid = foo->aBunchOfStrings;
    break;
}
std::cout << "Rows: " << grid->GetRows() << std::endl;
std::cout << "Col0 is: " << grid->GetTypeofColumn(0) << std::endl;
//...etc...
```

In the same way if I used subclasses like this: http://ideone.com/MPKy1w

I'm aware that class templates are almost basically macros and how the compiler actual compiles them, but is there no way to refer to the specializations generically and save repetition?

(I'm using pointers deliberately here, I have no choice in my actual code, which I can not copy here)

Comment: You want some polymorphism. There is static (overloading, templates) and dynamic (virtual functions). Just choose one.

Comment: But with polymorphism, wouldn't he have to define a derived class for every new class that he wants to encompass?

Comment: @Stephen not with templates

Comment: But what it the GetTypeOfColumn implementation depends on the type `T` in the template?

Comment: @Stephen not if the template itself is derived from the polymorphic base.

Comment: @Jonathan. then you specialize the template

Comment: I think I understand, so you would create a base class and then derive a templated class from it in order to hold it in an array or variable of the base class?

Comment: I've edited my question to show more what I mean.

Comment: @jaggedSpire and anyone else, could you post the example modified to show what you mean?

Comment: "But what it the GetTypeOfColumn implementation depends on the type T in the template?" Then make an *implementation* class template that inherits from a non-template interface class.

Answer (score 7):

Create class with desired methods ("interface"). It is possible to do so because your methods do not depend on template argument `T`:

```
class GridOperations {
    virtual int GetRows() = 0;
    virtual int getTypeOfColumn(int col) = 0;
    virtual ~GridOperations() {}
};
```

Now inherit Grid from above class:

```
template<T>
class Grid : public GridOperations {
  int GetRows() { /* impl */ }
  int GetTypeOfColumn(int col) { /* impl */ }
};
```

Now you may cast both `Grid<int>*` and `Grid<string>*` to `GridOperations*`:

```
Foo* foo;
GridOperations* ops;
switch wants {
  case NUMBERS:
    ops = foo->aBunchOfNumbers;
    break;
  case STRINGS:
    ops = foo->aBunchOfStrings;
    break;
}
std::cout << "Rows: " << ops->GetRows() << std::endl;
std::cout << "Col0 is: " << ops->GetTypeofColumn(0) << std::endl;
```

Bonus: and you may even use `std::map<WantEnumType, GridOperations*>` to avoid nasty switch block.

Comment: Thanks, what about a method that has a parameter of type T, eg. `GetValue(T* obj)`, which is called in a function that also takes a type T?  http://pastebin.com/BqTNQ8iD

Comment: In this case you declare your `someMemberFunction` also as a function template: [http://pastebin.com/RwSqxitR](http://pastebin.com/RwSqxitR). Idea is that if your class/function depends on smth. templated, then it (class/function) has also to be templated. You also have to understand that `Grid<string>` and `Grid<int>` are two different classes from compiler perspective (like Robot, PricingPolicy and GreenException). Templates are the way to create _families_ of similar functions and classes to avoid writing each of them separately.